# Kingfisher nil while unwrapping optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, kingfisher

I have `Medicine` struct that holds `image_origin` URL of image I want to download and set to the ImageView.
For downloading/caching purposes I'm using `Kingfisher` framework.

```
    let m = medicines[indexPath.row]

    cell.medicineImage.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: m.value(forKeyPath: "image_origin") as! String)!)
    cell.medicineName.text = m.value(forKeyPath: "i_name") as? String
```

In the code above `m` is an `NSManagedObject` of `CoreData`. I try to get image URI from the CoreData and set it to the ImageView, but every time at the line 2 I get the following error message: `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I have tried changing variables and Optinal types, tried to hardcode URI but without success.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Im using `Swift4`

Comment: Why `value(forKeyPath`? There is no key path. To get a value from a CoreData attribute use `value(forKey:` or – more convenient – dot notation in a `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Comment: @vadian well, i guess there are several possible notations. forKeyPath works like a charm to get value (according to the official CoreData example).

Comment: What is the link to *the official CoreData example*? I doubt that Apple suggests `forKeyPath` for just a one-level key.

Comment: @vadian if you jump to the definition of the NSManagedObject.value function, I will see the following function declaration: open func value(forKeyPath keyPath: String) -> Any?. As you can see the same function can accept parameter in different name forms.

Comment: This is a generic KVC method which any class adopting `NSObjectProtocol` responds to. Please read the [documenation of NSManagedObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject?changes=_2). The dedicated method to get a value for an one-level key is `value(forKey`. A key path is something like `"person.age"`. Of course `value(forKeyPath` works but is more expensive because it tries to separate and evaluate each path component.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for my misunderstanding and thanks for the link to the documentation :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unwrap safely to fix the crash and check your database if you are not getting the `urlString` properly,

```
if let urlString = m.value(forKeyPath: "image_origin") as? String {
   print(urlString)
   guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
   cell.medicineImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried your code, but I still got the following error `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. What else could fix that error?

Comment: Then i think you are doing a very basic error. Did you connect(Or initialized programmatically) `medicineImage` in your `cell`?

Comment: Yes, your are right! I don`t know why, but all my elements disconnected in the Storyboard, thus they were haven't been initialized. I reconnected them and all worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with `image_origin` key that I may have value as string or may not have. So, just need to confirm the value and use it

```
let m = medicines[indexPath.row]

cell.medicineName.text = m.value(forKeyPath: "i_name") as? String

guard let urlPath = m.value(forKeyPath: "image_origin") as? String, let url = URL(string: urlPath) else { return }
cell.medicineImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
```